# Insert data from spinner into database

Tags: android, database, spinner

HI. I have for instance the following code.

```
private EditText etAddSomething;
private EditText etAddSomething2;
private Spinner etAddSomethin3;

private String str_something;
private String str_something2;
private String str_something3;




str_descricao = etAddDescricao.getText().toString();
                            str_pais = etAddPais.getText().toString();
                            str_cidade = etAddCidade.getText().toString();
```

How can i insert data from spinner in the database? Using something like

```
str_descricao = etAddDescricao.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_spinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor cr = sqldb.rawQuery("select Name from employee",null);
```